# Store class generic in field in Java

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way to store the generic parameter type passed in at construction to a parameter.  My goal:

```
class generic<T> {
    Class<T> type;
    public generic() {
        super();
        this.type = //Something that gets class from T
    }
}
```

What I'm currently doing is this:

```
class generic<T> {
    Class<T> type;
    public generic(Class<T> type) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

It seems silly to have to specify the class twice, but I'm not sure of how else to do it.  I think this might be possible with reflection, but I haven't investigated that yet.  Is there a more straightforward way?  If not (as an aside) why the information loss?

Comment: If you are using generics, why do you want/need the class? This has a strange smell to it.

Comment: Agreed, you shouldn't need access to the generic parameter at runtime since generics are only a compile-type feature...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because Java generics are implemented with [Type Erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

> When a generic type is instantiated,
>   the compiler translates those types by
>   a technique called type erasure — a
>   process where the compiler removes all
>   information related to type parameters
>   and type arguments within a class or
>   method. Type erasure enables Java
>   applications that use generics to
>   maintain binary compatibility with
>   Java libraries and applications that
>   were created before generics.

Answer (score 8):

If you use a static creation method with type inference instead of the constructor, then the type does not need to be specified twice.

```
final class Generic<T> {
    private final Class<T> type;
    private Generic(Class<T> type) {
        super();
        if (type == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.type = type;
    }
    public static <T> Generic<T> newInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new Generic<T>(clazz);
    }
}
...
    someFunction(Generic.newInstance(SomeType.class));
```

Of course, if you want to store the result in a variable, you are probably going to repeat the type anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't do it because of [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 3):

They type is not preserved at runtime, so you cannot take it as a parameter. Generics in java are strictly a compile-time concept (for backwards compatability reasons). This is called [Type Erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

One of the reasons the class object takes a type parameter is precisely to work around this problem, so you can take the class object to represent the type programatically.